# Do you know if NFC can be used within an Android Instant App?

Tags: android, nfc, android-instant-apps

Did some research and got conflicting info.

The places that stipulate that NFC isn't supported by instant apps are quite old publications (2017).

However, the Android docs don't list NFC in the permissions:

https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle#configure-permissions

So, should I consider that NFC support is actually impossible?

Any recent info would help.

Thanks!